# How to instantiate FileSystemInfoBase in System.IO.Abstractions

Tags: unit-testing, filesystems

I am trying to write a file manager and have the following snippet:

```
    protected void InitializeObject(FileSystemInfo argInfo)
    {
        argInfo.Refresh();

        switch (argInfo)
        {
            case DirectoryInfo info:
... set Directory properties ...
            case FileInfo info:
... set File properties ...
        }
    }
```

This is followed in the subclass with type specific code.
How do I get a FileSystemInfo using System.IO.Abstractions?